# Odometer in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, odometer

I'm trying to run the Odometer, but it is not running in my JSX file. Am I following something wrong ? I can only see static numbers.

**Landing.jsx:**

```
import Odometer from 'react-odometerjs';
.
.
.
<div className="counter">
<div className="number odometer" id="datasources">
<Odometer value={11} format="(,ddd)"/></div>
<div className="label">underlying datasets</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You most probably forgot to add the styles to the page.
[Styles here](https://github.hubspot.com/odometer/api/themes/?__hstc=72727564.37d33886b7ec93c7a4f12b7909c47d7b.1550844055621.1583835105678.1583839707259.75&__hssc=72727564.1.1583839707259&__hsfp=4240080858)

Comment: You can check solution here : [Time out solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68979264/10147342)

Answer (score 0):

Try the format as:

```
<Odometer value={1234} format="(.ddd),dd" />
```

Comment: I'm adding styles in my file. But still unable to view required results.

Comment: Have you imported the styles from https://github.hubspot.com/odometer/api/themes/ ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a timer that changes the value of the innerHTML of the odometer element. The odometer class uses a MutationObserver to detect the change and update itself.

Answer (score 0):

- You need to put the type of animation. for example

```
<Odometer value={11} format="(,ddd)" animation="count"/>
```

- Don't forget to import the css file in your app .

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HubSpot/odometer/master/themes/odometer-theme-default.css