# How can I integrate React Odometerjs in Next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, odometer

It is very sad that after 3 days trying I still fail to integrate Odometer js in Next js. I can't understand where I wrong in my code. Here is my code in CodeSandBox - https://codesandbox.io/s/long-moon-z9zqu

this is code-

```
export default function Home() {
  const [odometerValue, setOdometerValue] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setOdometerValue(300);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Odometer
      value={odometerValue}
      format="(,ddd)"
      theme="default"
    />
  );
}
```

The npm pacjage I use - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-odometerjs

Please see the code and solve the problem who can. It will be very help full for me.

Comment: Can you provide more details on what's not working and what issues are you facing?

Comment: You can see on CodeSandBox, There no animation to changes value to final value.

Comment: Hello,  please help me to solve the problem. There is no counting animation on next js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that it's loading the `react-odometerjs` library dynamically, so the first time your `Home` component gets rendered, the library isn't loaded yet. So it renders the `loading` component of the `dynamic` options which just shows a 0. Because it's the first render your `useEffect` is run and that sets `odometerValue` to 300.

A little bit later, the `react-odometerjs` library is loaded which causes `Home` to rerender. Home renders the `Odometer` component, but now this renders the real `Odometer` component instead of the `loading` component so it will render like an odometer, but the value is set to 300 for the first load, so it just sits at 300.

If you add in a little delay before setting it to 300, then you can see it working. Here's an example:

```js
export default function Home() {
  const [odometerValue, setOdometerValue] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setOdometerValue(300);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Odometer
      value={odometerValue}
      format="(,ddd)"
      theme="default"
    />
  );
}
```

The problem with using a timer for this is that it can take different amounts of time for the library to actually load. The reason you need to load this library using `dynamic` is because you're using nextjs and it's doing Server Side Rendering (SSR) and when it does SSR it's rendering in nodejs which doesn't have the `document` or `window` globals defined and `odometer.js` uses those.

So you have some choices:

1. Use the `setTimeout` thing and get some slightly annoying behavior if the library loads slowly.
2. Use another library to get the odometer effect.
3. Fork the odometer library and remove it's dependency on `document` and `window` and then you can just use `import {Odometer} from 'react-odometerjs'` instead of using `dynamic`.
4. Implement something to let you know when the library has loaded on the client side, so that you can set the initial value after the library has loaded. I've put a hacky version of this below.

Hacky version to wait for library to load before setting `odometerValue`:

```js
let loadedCallback = null;
let loaded = false;

const Odometer = dynamic(async () => {
  const mod = await import("react-odometerjs");
  loaded = true;
  if (loadedCallback != null) {
    loadedCallback();
  }
  return mod;
}, {
  ssr: false,
  loading: () => 0
});

export default function Home() {
  const [odometerLoaded, setOdometerLoaded] = useState(loaded);
  const [odometerValue, setOdometerValue] = useState(0);
    
  loadedCallback = () => {
    setOdometerLoaded(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (odometerLoaded) {
      setOdometerValue(1);
    }
  }, [odometerLoaded]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setOdometerValue(300);
  }, [odometerValue]);

  return (
    <Odometer
      value={odometerValue}
      format="(,ddd)"
      theme="default"
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: It's working now. Thank you very much for describing me problem and answering the solve. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hello sir, I am getting another new error when I am trying to apply visibility sensor package? error is 'el.getBoundingClientRect is not a function'. Please help to solve this problem, Please please please, sir. Here is my code - https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-dream-ysi00?file=/pages/index.js:0-846